# In emacs, how do I configure fixed width for TAB in Fundamental mode?

Tags: emacs, tabs, customization

I have the following in my .emacs file:

```
(setq-default
    indent-tabs-mode nil
    tab-width 4
    tab-stop-list (quote (4 8 12 16))
)
```

But in my text file below, in the 3rd line, "3" lines up with "12" when I press TAB; it seems to base on the "D" column in the line above. I wanted "3" to line up at 8 instead. How do I achieve that?

```
0   4   8   12  16
AB  C       D
1   2       3
```

Thank you.

Comment: The example (with tabs instead of spaces) works just fine with Emacs 25.3 without any user configuration other than that mentioned in the question above.  You may wish to turn on `whitespace-mode` so that you can see how many tabs are really there.  The space between the C and D could only be true of there were two (2) tabs present.  The space between the 2 and 3 could only be true if there were two (2) tabs present.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to change what TAB does to `tab-to-tab-stop`

i.e, place the following somewhere in your .emacs file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```